# SAS Proc SQL - ranking top nth (3rd) highest for a group of say universities and their price? (HW to be honest)

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, ranking-functions

(this is homework, not going to lie)

I have an ANSI SQL query I wrote

this produces
the required
3rd highest prices correctly,

table sample is

```
select unique uni, price
from
(
(
     select unique uni, price
     from 
     (
          select unique uni, price
          from table1
          group by uni
          having price < max(price)
     )
     group by uni
     having price < max(price)
) 
group by uni
having price < max(price)
)
```

now i need to list the 1st, 2nd and 3rd into one table but make is such that it could be used nth times.

```
  example:
  Col1    Col2    
  uni1    10
  uni1    20
  uni2    20
  uni2    10
  uni3    30
  uni3    20
  uni1    30
```

/*sorry for the formatting i havent been here for a very long time, i appreciate any assistance, i will supply a link to the uni of which i have asked the tutor if i can do so he said yes but not the whole code, something like 10%, but anyways.*/

Comment: You should (at least) put the query in as text in the question, not an image.  The data is better as text tables too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, i will fix that now

Comment: @GordonLinoff hey, may I ask you how do I draw a table here. I got mixed results when googling.

Comment: The way to provide data for SAS posts is as a stand alone data step with in-line data so users can copy and paste into a SAS session to reproduce your example data.

Answer (score 0):

In SAS you can use the proprietary option `OUTOBS` to restrict how many rows of a result set are output.

Example:

Use `OUTOBS=3` to create *top 3* table.  Then use that table in a subsequent query.

```
data have;
input x @@; datalines;
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
;

proc sql;
  reset outobs=3;
  create table top3x as
  select * from have
  order by x descending;

  reset outobs=max;
  * another query;
quit;
```